# Fibonacci datatype

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ienumerable

I'm writing a Fibonacci series generator and I'm not sure which datatype should I use for it. This is what I'm doing:

- Generate the first 1000 numbers in a Fibonacci series and store it in a collection.
- Shuffle the above series (i.e juggle the elements)and store it in a new collection.
- Create a new collection by transforming the above 2 collections by the following rule- every element in the new collection will be an average of the respective elements in the first 2 collections, residing in the same index. i.e newcollection[0]= (original[0]+shuffle[0])/2.

I have decided that my original collection and the shuffled collection should be an `IEnumerable<long>`. The averaged out collection should be `IEnumerable<double>`, do you think this is correct? Should I be using `IEnumerable<decimal>` for the averaged out collection?

Note:Eventually all the collections are flushed to the console.

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: via Jon Skeet: "For values which are "naturally exact decimals" it's good to use decimal. This is usually suitable for any concepts invented by humans: financial values are the most obvious example, but there are others too. Consider the score given to divers or ice skaters, for example." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IEnumerable<long>` is fine for an (infinite) generator.

However, the `IEnumerable` interface does not guarantee constant (O(1)) random access to the elements, which is required at least for the shuffling. So you should store the results of the generator into an `IList<long>` or into a simple array.

EDIT:

I did a little research, and it seems that even the 100th Fibonacci number cannot fit into a long ([check Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fibonacci%20number%20100)). You have to use some [big integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) data type here...

Comment: It's not an infinite generator, it's only generating the first 1000 elements in the fibonacci series.

Comment: @Mike, OK, then just use directly a List or an array. The real problem here is that the 1000th Fibonacci number is ~4.3x10^209, so you have to resort to some big numerals library... `long`, `int`, `float` or `decimal` are way too small.

Comment: :The max value for double is 1.7976931348623157E+308 and the 1000th fibonacci number is 4.34*10^208. So should't it support?

Comment: From wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point): `any integer with absolute value less than or equal to 2^53 can be exactly represented in the double precision format`. So, you will have only approximations for the numbers above that limit.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use just standard Arrays? int[1000] and double[1000]?

Comment: Becuase I would like to use lazy evaluation of LINQ. The whole point of the app is to verify the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `List<int>`, because Fibonacci elements are integers.

Comment: They are not. Only the first 46 elements of the series can fit into an `int`.