# Datatype for fibonacci numbers

Tags: c#, types, numbers, fibonacci

As I am currently learning C#, I made a small program to calculate X amount of fibonacci numbers. However, as the numbers quickly get quite large, not even an unsigned long can hold the numbers. How do I solve this problem? Make my own superlarge integer datatype?

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362703/fibonacci-datatype

Comment: Use [Int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yy583ek.aspx)? Max value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, sounds reasonable!

Comment: @StigHausberg: Sorry, I didn't see that.

Comment: @Shai: Even a `UInt64` can only hold the first 94 fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using .NET4 or newer? If so you could use [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. BigInteger works great. Will mark this as the answer when the timer allows me to.

Answer (score 2):

No data type will be able to hold all the numbers. There are too many.

The solvability of your problem depends critically on the upper bound you put on X. Depending on which it is, `BigInteger` can be a possibility, as [LukeH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9481161/96780) says.

Comment: Obviously it cannot store _all_ the numbers as the sequence is infinite. All I want is a lot of them. :D

Comment: The Fibonnaci numbers form an infinite countable set, there can never be 'too many'! :D

Answer (score 2):

you can do `String` sum processing for a calculate too many fib number. also can use  `BigInteger` for limited number